# Cannot access local variables using systemtap

Tags: 13.04, kernel, 64-bit, system, debug

I am just getting started using systemtap. On my 64bit Ubuntu 13.04 system, I installed systemtap and dependencies + systemtap-doc and elfutils then added the ddep repository to my apt/sources.list and installed the dbgsym package for my kernel (3.8.0-29.42).

I then tried running the examples in /usr/share/doc/systemtap-doc/examples/general (e.g., key.stp), but I got

```
semantic error: not accessible at this address [man error::dwarf] ... identifier '$event_type' at key.stp:8:7
```

I then ran the "Work around broken dbgsym file layount..."-script as described at [wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Systemtap](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Systemtap)

Still the same error and similar errors occur running the other scripts whenever a local variable is accessed.

So I wrote a little script following section "Determine local variables at probe point" on the same page to give me a list of local variables in kbd_event.

```
probe begin {
  printf ("probe installed")
}

probe kernel.function("kbd_event") {
  printf ("%s locals [%s]\n", probefunc(), $$locals)
  exit()
}
```

which gives me

```
probe installed
kbd_event locals []
```

So it looks like stap doesn't see any local variables and this is where I am stuck.

Any ideas what I am missing or what I could try next?

Thanks!

PS: The same procedure works fine on my 64bit 12.04 with 3.2.0-49.75 kernel.

Update: I now even rebuild the kernel with debugging symbols using gcc 4.7, but still no improvement.